# Javascript how to filter 2d array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array, filter, split

I need to filter an array, so I've this code that works for a normal array

```
var arr = [138,124,128,126,140,113,102,128,136,110,134,132,130,132,132,104,116,135,120];

var limit = 112;

var lowarray = arr.filter(function(x) {
    return x <= limit;
});

var higharray = arr.filter(function(x) {
    return x > limit;
});

console.log(lowarray);
console.log('');
console.log(higharray);
```

The problem is that I've to apply it to a 2d array but I tried and no results!

for example I've this array

```
var arr [[1,5],[2,4],[3,6],[4,2],[5,2]];
```

I wanna split it with the same idea

```
var limit = 3;
```

so the lowarray would be

```
[[1,5],[2,4],[3,6]];
```

and the higharray would be

```
[[4,2],[5,2]];
```

Any Idea?

Comment: So what is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`return x[0] > limit;`

Since you seem to want to filter on the first element of the 2d array